# Root Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Logger

Tags: java, logging

.classpath:

```
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/com.ibm.mq.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/com.ibm.mqjms.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/dhbcore.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/jms.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/mailapi.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

I see Exception in thread **"main"**

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger.

I am using **java version 8**. Need help regarding what's wrong in lib's.